# Spring relationships returning empty result

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest

I am creating a REST API with spring, and I have a few classes

```kotlin
@Table
@Entity
data class NightShift (
    @Id
    override val date:String,
    @ManyToOne
    var mod: Manager,
    @OneToMany
    var pca:Set<PCA>
):Shift
```

and

```kotlin
@Table(uniqueConstraints = [UniqueConstraint(columnNames =["item", "shift_date"])])
@Entity
data class PCA (
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id:Long = 0,
    @ManyToOne
    val shift: NightShift,
    val item:String,
    val amount: Double,
    val autoload:Boolean
)
```

Spring created a pca table, and a nightshift table, as well as a third night_shift_pca table to join them.

I have retrieved a Shift object, however whenever I try and get the pca objects from that it returns an empty list?

Thanks in advance